# Installing SQL Server Express 2005 from VS setup project - named instance

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, installation, setup-project

I'm installing SQL Server Express 2005 from my Visual Studio 2008 setup project.

This works fine and installs the instance "SQLExpress".

Does anyone know if you can pass it some kind of command line to install or change a property to give it a different instance name?

Comment: It might help if you describe exactly how you invoke the Sql Server installation from your setup project.

Comment: Just the standard setup project pre-requisites bootstrapper (so it does it itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this article on how to edit the bootstrapper that installs SQL as part of the setup. There is indeed an INSTANCENAME attribute (and you can also pass DEFAULTDATABASE and all sorts of useful command line parameters).

http://www.windowsdevelop.com/clickonce-setup--deployment-projects/generic-bootstrapper--sql-express-named-instance-18693.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling out to SQL Server's setup.exe from your installer I believe you can pass the instance name as an argument, like this: `setup.exe INSTANCENAME=YourInstance`

See here for more info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(SQL.90).aspx